# Changing object in array using useState

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to change each `Data[0].datasets label`  using the array in `Axis`state

I tried to put `Axis`'s `label` to each `Data` `label` but i doesn't work, and it's not what i expected it would be.

both are changed to as same as the last one that i write.

and I'm trying to add more elements to `datasets` using the `AxisHandler` function to use `push`.

and It's doesn't change as soon as i click `AxisUpdate`function.

I'd like to know why it happens and what i should do .

Thank you in advance.

my code is like this:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Data, AppendData } from "./Data";

const Changeable = () => {
  const [Axis, setAxis] = useState([]);

  const changeHandler = index => e => {
    setAxis(Axis =>
      Axis.map((el, i) => (i === index ? { ...el, label: e.target.value } : el))
    );
  };

  const AxisHandler = e => {
    setAxis([
      ...Axis,
      {
        label: "",
        data: "",
        backgroundColor: "",
      },
    ]);
    Data[0].datasets.push(AppendData);
  };

  const AxisUpdate = () => {
    if (Data[0].datasets[1].label) {
      Data[0].datasets[1].label = Axis[0].label;
    }
    if (Data[0].datasets[2].label) {
      Data[0].datasets[2].label = Axis[1].label;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={AxisHandler}>addAxis</button>

      <>
        {Axis.map((data, index) => (
          <>
            <input
              placeholder={index + 1}
              type="text"
              onChange={changeHandler(index)}
            />
          </>
        ))}
      </>
      <button onClick={AxisUpdate}>changeLabel</button>
      <br />
      <h1>{Data[0].datasets[0].label}</h1>
      <br />
      <h1>{Data[0].datasets[1] && Data[0].datasets[1].label}</h1>
      <br />
      <h1>{Data[0].datasets[2] && Data[0].datasets[2].label}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Changeable;
```

## `Data` and `AppendData`

```js
export const defaultLabels = [
  "0",
  "0",
  "0",
  "0",
  "5",
  "6",
  "7",
  "8",
  "9",
  "10",
  "11",
  "12",
];
export const defaultDatas = [
  13000, 11000, 9000, 4000, 14000, 16000, 20000, 11000, 14000, 11200, 12000,
  12000,
];
export const defaultBackgroundColor = [
  "#ff6385e1",
  "#36a3ebf0",
  "#ffcf56c8",
  "#4bc0c0be",
  "#9966ffa2",
  "#ffa040b2",
];
export let AppendData = {
  label: "dataSetting",
  data: defaultDatas,
  backgroundColor: defaultBackgroundColor,
};
export let Data = [
  {
    labels: defaultLabels,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "First",
        data: defaultDatas,
        backgroundColor: defaultBackgroundColor,
      },
    ],
  }, ///1번
  {
    labels: defaultLabels,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Second",
        data: defaultDatas,
        backgroundColor: defaultBackgroundColor,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    labels: defaultLabels,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Third",
        data: defaultDatas,
        backgroundColor: defaultBackgroundColor,
      },
    ],
  },
]; ///2번
```

Comment: React will only trigger a re-render when state has changed. AxisUpdate is out of scope and will not cause a re-render and you will not see updates.
You need to store Data in local state.

Comment: does it mean that i should put `Data` in `Axis` state ??

Comment: what do you mean `It's doesn't change as soon as i click AxisUpdatefunction.`? Not re-render or something?

Comment: it means not re render

Comment: when you click AxisUpdate, only Data changed, component will not rerender, util setAxis executed.

Comment: Thank you all u guys!  I have a question. then should I use `Data` as state ??

Comment: Yes. Its better to store the `Data` in state. Bcz updating data and forceUpdate will be complicated otherwise